# Surjectivity from a order unit space $A$ to the affine function space on the state space of $A$?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, vector-lattices

In the proof for the theorem in the picture snipped off the book *State Spaces of Operator Algebras* by Erik M. Alfsen & Frederic W. Shultz, where is the Hahn-Banach Theorem is applied? As far as I can see, only Stone-Weierstrass Theorem is applied, which follows $\{\hat{a}|a\in A\}$ is dense in $C(K)$:

- $\hat{1}(\rho)=\rho(1)=1, \forall \rho\in K$, so, $\hat{1}$ is a constant function in $C(K)$;
- For distinct states $\mu,\nu$ on $A$, of course we can find some $a\in A$ such that $\mu(a)\neq \nu(a)$, so, $\hat{a}(a\in A)$ separate the points of $K$.

Since $\hat{a}(a\in A)$ is affine on $K$, $C(K)=A(K)$.

[image]

Comment: How do you go from "dense range" to "surjective" without Hahn-Banach?

Comment: @MartinArgerami If $A$ is complete, the range will also be complete since the map is an isometry. Anything wrong?

Comment: I think you are right. I was thinking about a different statement.

Comment: When I get  back to this theorem today,  I find  where the problem is:  $ \{\hat{a}|a\in  A\} $ is  not necessarily a SUBALGEBRA,  which is the precondition of Stone-Weierstrass Theorem.

Comment: Indeed, good point!